# Intermittent SSLHandshake exception in rms sdk

Tags: java, android, adal, rights-management

I'm using microsoft's ADAL library and RMS 4.2.  I have compiled and build rms sample app using android studio. I have imported same libraries in my app as well but I'm facing an issue both in sample app and mine one. Below is the exception trace and network call which fails.

Stacktrace a bit lengthy so I have avoided UI cluttering (please refer http://pastebin.com/xavNPj80 ), also I was unable to find any help on microsoft's developer forum.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). You may also want to check [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Post the code you have tried and the errors you have received. Be as specific as possible as it will lead to better answers.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, purpose of this question is to get attention of microsoft's active developers on rms sdk. Since error is coming itself from jar so adding it's code is irrelevant here. For more info ADAL (https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-android) and rms sdk 4.2 sample app (https://github.com/AzureAD/rms-sdk-ui-for-android)